# Django Misconfiguration

Tags: django, apache

I am trying to deploy [mayan-edms](http://www.mayan-edms.com) a django web application on a RedHat5.6 server in production mode with apache webserver.

I have setup the database and the used a virtual-env to setup the env

This is my httpd.conf

```
WSGIScriptAlias /mayan /var/www/mayan/mayan/wsgi/dispatch.wsgi
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/mayan/mayan:/var/www/mayan/lib/python2.6/site-packages
<Directory /var/www/mayan/mayan>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I am getting a 500 error if I start apache with this conf. Could anyone tell me where it is getting misconfigured?

This is the error

```
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48] mod_wsgi (pid=21715): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mayan/mayan/wsgi/dispatch.wsgi'.
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48]   File "/var/www/mayan/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48]     self.load_middleware()
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48]   File   "/var/www/mayan/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48]     mod = import_module(mw_module)
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48]   File "/var/www/mayan/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48]     __import__(name)
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48]   File "/var/www/mayan/mayan/apps/common/__init__.py", line 17
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48]      from .conf.settings import (AUTO_CREATE_ADMIN, AUTO_ADMIN_USERNAME,
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48]           ^
[Mon Jan 14 12:47:02 2013] [error] [client 130.229.146.48]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is my init.py around line 17

```
from django.db import transaction,  DatabaseError 
from navigation.api import register_links, register_top_menu 
from .conf.settings import (AUTO_CREATE_ADMIN, AUTO_ADMIN_USERNAME, AUTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD, TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY) 
from .conf import settings as common_settings
from .utils import validate_path 
from .models import AutoAdminSingleton
```

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: @antoyo I was just adding it and you asked for it :)

Comment: the traceback is complaining about `/var/www/mayan/mayan/apps/common/__init__.py` line 17 - can you include the file (or just the relevant part around line 17 if it's big)

Comment: They are standard imports, seem to work as I did not change any source code  Here is the relevant lines anyway .... from django.db import transaction, DatabaseError

from navigation.api import register_links, register_top_menu

from .conf.settings import (AUTO_CREATE_ADMIN, AUTO_ADMIN_USERNAME,
    AUTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD, TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY)
from .conf import settings as common_settings
from .utils import validate_path
from .models import AutoAdminSingleton

Comment: please put the lines from __init__.py into the question - they are totally illegible in the comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22713/discussion-between-pavan-k-and-scytale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a Python version issue. RHEL 5.6 appears to be quite an old release, and anyway Red Hat are known for bundling old versions of Python. Looking at [this table](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat) it seems likely that that version of RHEL was not even Python 2.4.

From the other side, the minimum Python version to run the current Django release is 2.7. Although that said, the requirements.txt file for your app actually asks for Django 1.3.5 - but you will still need at least Python 2.6 for that. You will either need to compile and install that version yourself, or upgrade your version of Red Hat.

Comment: I have installed python2.6 and in the virtual-env I specified the same. I linked the 2.6 version using WSGIPythonPath /var/www/mayan/mayan:/var/www/mayan/lib/python2.6/site-packages thinking it will take the installed 2.6 version. Let me know if I am missing something here

Comment: Ah, unfortunately it doesn't work like that. You will need to recompile mod_wsgi with the new Python version.

Comment: I installed mod_wsgi using yum. How do I recompile and set it up. Any pointers??

Comment: You'll need to download the source, use `configure` to set the dependencies, then `make`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Building mod_wsgi and linking it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are using python 2.6, the [documentation](https://mayan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro/installation.html) for installation seems to use python 2.7